# list manipulation

Tags: list, lisp

I am a lisp novice and I am trying to manipulate lists in lisp. The is from practical tutorial in uni. When i call the function the first element in the list need to be incremented by one and the rest to remain as it was.
Here is an example:

```
(inc-1st '(1 2 3 4))  =>  (2 2 3 4)
```

I tried to solve it but my first number from the list is not printing. Here is my code:

```
(defun inc-1st (list)
    (and (+ 1(car list)) (cdr list)))
```

and the output is: `(2 3 4)`

Comment: The `homework` tag is obsolete and being removed, if you want detailed or explanatory help just point it out in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard CL macro [INCF](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_incf_.htm) will do what you want:

```
[1]> (defparameter list (list 1 2 3))
LIST
[2]> (incf (first list))
2
[3]> list
(2 2 3)
```

(Try `(macroexpand (incf (first list)))` to see how it works.)

Thus your function would be something like

```
(defun inc-1st (list)
  (incf (first list))
  list)
```

Note the difference between printing  value and returning it: the function above **returns** `list` while the REPL prints the return value.

Comment: chers mate, exactly what I needed